# Registering multiple observers for twisted logger

Tags: python, logging, twisted

I have written a custom tcp observer that sends message over network to be parsed by logstash.

In my application I'd like to log stuffs like this:

1. "acme" namespace [info] goes to one logstash server
2. "acme" namespace [debug, critical, warning] goes to another
3. "" namespace [info, debug] (twisted logs) goes to info file
4. "" namespace [warning, critical] (twisted errors) goes to error file

Is it possible to achieve this with one single logger ? or should I register multiple loggers ?

The problem seems to be that the observers can be registered in two places:

- `twisted.Logger.globalLogBeginner` but this registers obs for ALL loggers
- `logger.Logger(observer=)` but this can register only a single observer

Can I achieve what I want to do with one single logger or should I register multiple loggers ? For points **1** and **2** I will have two loggers, a "customer" and a "debug", but if possible I'd rather avoid the **3** and **4** to be a different logger than the **debug** one.

Here what I have tried actually:

```
from twisted import logger
from twisted.internet import reactor

from txlab.logger import LogstashLogObserver

# Global object to control globally namespace logging
logLevelFilterPredicate = logger.LogLevelFilterPredicate(defaultLogLevel=logger.LogLevel.info)


def startLogging(console=True, filepath=None, errpath=None):
    """
    Starts the global Twisted logger subsystem with maybe
    stdout and/or a file specified in the config file
    """
    global logLevelFilterPredicate

    observers = []
    if console:
        observers.append(logger.FilteringLogObserver(observer=logger.textFileLogObserver(sys.stdout),
                                                     predicates=[logLevelFilterPredicate]))

    if filepath is not None and filepath != "":
        observers.append(logger.FilteringLogObserver(observer=logger.textFileLogObserver(open(filepath, 'a')),
                                                     predicates=[logLevelFilterPredicate]))
    if errpath is not None and errpath != "":
        _logLevelFilterPredicate = logger.LogLevelFilterPredicate(defaultLogLevel=logger.LogLevel.error)
        observers.append(logger.FilteringLogObserver(observer=logger.textFileLogObserver(open(errpath, 'a')),
                                                     predicates=[_logLevelFilterPredicate]))
    logger.globalLogBeginner.beginLoggingTo(observers)


def setLogLevel(namespace=None, levelStr='info'):
    """
    Set a new log level for a given namespace
    LevelStr is: 'critical', 'error', 'warn', 'info', 'debug'
    """
    level = logger.LogLevel.levelWithName(levelStr)
    logLevelFilterPredicate.setLogLevelForNamespace(namespace=namespace, level=level)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    logInfo = logger.Logger(observer=LogstashLogObserver(b'127.0.0.1', 5001, version=1))
    logDebug = logger.Logger(observer=LogstashLogObserver(b'127.0.0.1', 5002, version=1))

    startLogging(filepath='/code/txacme/_logs/info.log',
                 errpath='/code/txacme/_logs/errors.log')

    setLogLevel(namespace='', levelStr='debug')

    """
    The problem here is that when logging, I cannot use the logDebug to log twisted events,
    I need to create another logger without an observer to be able to use the globally registered ones
    """
    logTwisted = logger.Logger()  # I want to avoid this, using logDebug instead

    try:
        raise IOError()
    except:
        log.failure('errrrrr')

    log.info("Some values: {values!r}", values=[1234, 5678])
    log.info("Some values: {values!r}", values=[9876, 5432])
    log.info('{a}, {b}, {c}, that\'s all :)', a=1, b=2, c=3)
    reactor.run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can register multiple Log Observers to a single logger through `twisted.logger.globalLogPublisher`. `globalLogPublisher` is designed by Composite pattern. That is, it itself is an observer, and can have another observers. Logger will register `globalLogPublisher` unless an observer is explicitly specified in the constructor. You can do something like

```py
import sys
from twisted.logger import globalLogPublisher, textFileLogObserver, Logger
from txlab.logger import LogstashLogObserver

log = Logger()
globalLogPublisher.addObserver(LogstashLogObserver(b'127.0.0.1', 5001, version=1))
globalLogPublisher.addObserver(LogstashLogObserver(b'127.0.0.1', 5002, version=1))
globalLogPublisher.addObserver(textFileLogObserver(sys.stdout))

# this will publish logging event to all observers registered in globalLobPublisher.
log.info('some message')
```